# AIR NativeProcess does the job, but it sends progress data to ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA

Tags: apache-flex, air

In Flex AIR application, I would like to upload file to ftp-server with NativeProcess API and curl.
Here is the simplified code:

```
protected function startProcess(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var processInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    processInfo.executable = new File('/usr/bin/curl');
    var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
    processArgs.push("-T");                 
    processArgs.push("/Users/UserName/Desktop/001.mov");                    
    processArgs.push("ftp://domainIp//www/site.com/");                  
    processArgs.push("--user");                 
    processArgs.push("username:password");                  
    processInfo.arguments = processArgs;

    var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
    process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, outputDataHandler);
    process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, errorOutputDataHandler);
    process.start(processInfo);
}
```

It does the job well (i.e. target file is uploaded), but it emits `ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA` instead of `ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA` and all progress data goes to `process.standardError`.

```
protected function errorOutputDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var process = event.currentTarget as NativeProcess;
    trace(process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable));
}
```

Here is an output of the latter function:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

1 15.8M    0     0    1  200k      0   166k  0:01:37  0:00:01  0:01:36  177k

2 15.8M    0     0    2  381k      0   143k  0:01:53  0:00:02  0:01:51  146k

...
```

What's wrong with my code? How can I debug it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is curl's progress meter. Try the `-sS` option to disable it but keep error messages.

Comment: This is because curl writes information to stderror in order to not pollute stdout.

Comment: Is it safe to read information from stderror in order to give progress to the user?